# Infinitely differentiable functions and sequences

Tags: real-analysis, proof-writing

I have been completely stuck in proving the following statement:

> Let $\{c_n\}_{n \in \Bbb N}$ be a complex-valued sequence, then there exists a function $f: \Bbb R \to \Bbb C$ such that $\forall n \in \Bbb N, f^{(n)}(0) = c_n n!$

---

As always any comment or answer is welcome and let me know if I can explain myself clearer.

Comment: @Lorago But what if $c_n=n^n$? Then $f$ is not defined on a interval containing 0, but just at 0. Hence it is not differentiable.

Comment: @Lorago That need not converge

Comment: This is an exercise somewhere in Rudin _Real and Complex Analysis_; I suspect there's some sort of hint or outline given there...